# exporting keras tf2 to cpp

Tags: python, c++, keras, tensorflow2.x

I have trained my Keras model with TensorFlow 2.2 version. Now have to deploy it in CPP i.e. wants its inference/predictions in c++ language. Using [fraugly](https://github.com/Dobiasd/frugally-deep) I have successfully deployed it but it's giving me prediction in 0.3sec whereas I need to run prediction in search tree this time is too much for me. I want my results at least in milliseconds. Can anyone provide me any help regarding this?

PS: I also tried other GitHub like pocket tensor, gosha-kerasify,pplonski etc either they were for TensorFlow 1.x or have some missing layers I am not CPP expert having so much trouble in it